# Spring Boot autoconfig is still taking Tomcat Datasource instead HikariCP?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, datasource, hikaricp

I have my Spring Boot 1.2.5.RELEASE service and I want to use the `HikariCP` datasource instead of the default tomcat-jdbc. So, according to this [Spring Boot Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connect-to-production-database) I understand I just have to exclude `tomcat-jdbc` from the classpath and add `HikariCP`.

So this is my pom.xml:

```xml
...
<dependencyManagement>
    ...
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
...
```

maven dependency tree:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ myproject-user-manage-webservice ---
[INFO] com.mybusiness.myproject:myproject-user-manage-webservice:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.mybusiness.myproject:myproject-commons:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.mybusiness.myproject:myproject-core:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.mybusiness.myproject:myproject-core-commons:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- com.mybusiness.myproject:myproject-api:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.4.4:compile (version managed from 2.4.6)
[INFO] |  \- com.mybusiness.myproject:myproject-framework:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 1.2.5.RELEASE)
[INFO] |     +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.34:compile (version managed from 5.1.35)
[INFO] |     +- com.mybusiness.framework:despegar-fwk-logging:jar:1.4.148:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.jenkins-ci.plugins:testInProgress-client:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.json:json:jar:20140107:compile
[INFO] |     +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.mybusiness.myproject:myproject-user-manage-domain:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.4:compile (version managed from 1.8.2)
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 4.0.7.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.7.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.9.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-jwt:jar:1.0.2.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 1.0.3.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.47:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.47:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.flywaydb:flyway-core:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.14:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.0.15:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.0.15:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:jar:8.0.15:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.0.15:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.1.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:test (scope not updated to compile)
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.8:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.8:compile (version managed from 1.7.7)
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:jar:2.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:jar:0.16.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 3.2.9.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.8:compile (version managed from 1.7.7)
[INFO] +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:2.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] +- ma.glasnost.orika:orika-core:jar:1.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:jar:1.2_jdk5:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.carrotsearch:java-sizeof:jar:0.0.4:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.0.0.Beta4:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] \- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:jar:2.1.1:compile
```

So, `HikariCP` is definitely in tha classpath and `tomcat-jdbc` is not. But when I launch the service, `autoconfig` is still creating org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource instead of a `HikariCP` one.

What I am doing wrong?

---

### EDIT

This is my application launcher:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = {HypermediaType.HAL})
public class ApplicationRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationRunner.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: How are you launching the service?

Comment: Please check it out my update

Comment: Try clean the project, maybe the jar is still on output of your artifact.

Comment: Are you running the jar from the command line or launching the main class from your IDE. (If the latter can you mention your IDE) at least try running the jar from the command line.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse. sorry i  forgot to mention that. Its giving me error from command line but i think that is because something related with multi module project . And from eclipse is still happening after cleaning up and update project

Comment: Can you verify that you don't have this class `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource` on your classpath, on eclipse Open type (ctrl+shif+t) type DataSource, does this class `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource` appear on the list?

Comment: Try the simplest thing first. Try cleaning your project to ensure that the tomcat jar isn't there.

Also are you sure that you don't have any context defined in XML that might be sneaking onto your classpath?

Comment: I've just reinstalled eclipse (for another reason) and went all ok. I don't know what was the problem since i cleaned and updated the project a lot of times. Thanks all of you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Edit: This answer gives the way to configure Hikari in standard Spring, also valid for Boot. However, as Boot has added greater integration for Hikari since I wrote it, answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34909326/1199132) could be valid and more suitable for Boot.*

Just provide the datasource in a `@Configuration` class:

```
@Configuration
public class HikariCPConfig {

    @Value("${hikari.driverclassname}")
    private String driverClassName;

    @Value("${hikari.jdbc.url}")
    private String jdbcUrl;

    @Value("${hikari.username}")
    private String userName;

    @Value("${hikari.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${hikari.pool.size}")
    private int poolSize;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource();
        ds.setMaximumPoolSize(poolSize);
        ds.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        ds.setJdbcUrl(jdbcUrl);
        ds.setUsername(userName);
        ds.setPassword(password);
        return ds;
    }

}
```

Then, in the `application.properties` file, declare your properties for the datasource, which can be provided by the maven build:

```
#Hikari
hikari.driverclassname = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hikari.jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db
hikari.username = ${db.username}
hikari.password = ${db.password}
hikari.pool.size = 5
```

Then you'll need Spring to scan your `HikariCPConfig` class, but as you're using `@SpringBootApplication` which is equivalent to `@Configuration` `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan` it shouldn't be a problem.

**See also:**

- [Using the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html)
- [Configuring a datasource in Spring Boot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-a-datasource)

Comment: Since this is a valid solution, i was trying to avoid this way to take advantage from Spring Boot auto configuration. But if the problem persists i am definitely going with this. Thanks!

Comment: I know, but tomcat connection is failing In prod due it closes when is inactive for a while. I red that maybe this wouldn't happen with hikaricp (or I have to set test connection for each request which would reduce performance a lot)

Comment: I solved the problem, (but i don't know how actually :P). Just reinstalled eclipse for another reason and all OK. Thanks! Accept you answer since that is a solution anyways

Comment: This might sound a little patetic, but i don't even know what was going on... i've just reinstalled eclipse (for other reason) and it just worked... it was an eclipse-cache related problem maybe? It's weird because i tried cleaning the proyect and updating dependencies without success. Anyways, i will try to reproduce the error tomorrow and see what happen :-)

Comment: @jscherman, I recently ran into the same problem with the Tomcat connection pool (it was being closed after a while, only in production). I solved it with this configuration: `spring.datasource.test-on-borrow: true` and `spring.datasource.validation-query: SELECT 1`. That way you force the pool to validate each connection.

Answer (score 18):

- Include Hikari in your pom
- Add the following property to your application.yml

  ```
  spring:
    datasource:
      type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
      ...
  ```

Answer (score 1):

spring.datasouce.type starts with spring boot 1.3.0, so it won't work on 1.2.5

Comment: What do you mean? Where am i using spring.datasource.type?

Comment: If you are working with 1.3.0+, you can specify the property spring.datasouce.type, otherwise you must define a bean to override spring-boot autoconfiguration.

Comment: I assume that your comment was in respo se to @Ben comment. I get what you say but in the time i made this question,  as you say, i couldnt't use the   datasour r type param. The way to do it was i said the documentation mentioned: taking hikari from the classpath. The problem is that it wasn't working either. Then after reinstalling eclipse the problem was gone weirdly so i don't know what was the problem

Comment: If you deploy the war to tomcat's webapps directory. tomcat-jdbc lib is already there. spring-boot will search tomcat-jdbc before hikaricp. So you configuration won't work. I had written a sample. https://github.com/zhanhb/spring-boot-druid-sample/blob/1442b5441d4632c30d15cff8c92c4948a27b2fa2/src/main/java/com/github/zhanhb/customdatasource/config/CustomDataSource.java